# Que signifie cette phrase « Si l'on glissait pas dessus, on serait toujours en larmes, c'est à dire moi. » ?

Tags: sens

> Si l'on glissait pas dessus, on serait toujours en larmes, c'est à dire moi.

C'est un extrait d'une lettre de Madame de Sévigné pour sa fille.

Answer (score 5):

C'est extrait d'une lettre adressée à sa fille et datée du 3 mars 1671 :

«…Je vous assure, ma chère bonne, que je songe à vous continuellement, et je sens tous les jours ce que vous me dîtes une fois, qu'il ne fallait point appuyer sur ces pensées.  Si l'on ne glissait par dessus, on serait toujours en larmes, c'est-à-dire moi.…»

La citation exacte de la phrase est donc : « Si l'on **ne** glissait **par** dessus, on serait toujours en larmes, c'est-à-dire moi. »

Le contexte est le suivant, Françoise-Marguerite, la fille de Mme de Sévigné, a quitté Paris au début de février pour aller rejoindre son mari à Grignan en Provence.  Leur séparation est toute récente.  Mme de Sévigné, malgré le conseil que lui a donné sa fille de ne pas trop penser à elle, *de ne pas appuyer sur ces pensées*, y pense toujours.  Elle n'arrive pas à s'en empêcher, *à glisser par dessus*.  *Glisser* est à prendre ici dans le sens d'ignorer, de ne pas prêter attention à quelque chose.

La phrase est formulée de manière générale avec *l'on* et *on* dans un premier temps mais Mme de Sévigné ramène la situation à elle en ajoutant *c'est-à-dire moi*.  Ce qu'elle veut dire, c'est : *si je n'ignorais pas ces pensées, je serais toujours en larmes*.